# XSLT 2.0 anlayze-string option not working?

Tags: regex, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a xml structure like below

```
 <warning file="project\Src\a.c" line="45" message="intended 7.7. 3218 Decl File scope static, 'DSVS_SLOW_CH_RCVD_INFO_INIT', only accessed in one function."/>
 <warning file="project\Src\x.c" line="132" message="deviation 3218 Decl File scope static,">
```

I want file line and message to come in a table format. Message is matched against a regex and has to be taken.

Message contains rank -(intended or deviation)  optional standard, rule and description. and it is separated by a space

In my example first tag has
file= project\Src\a.c , line = 45 , rank = intended , standard 7.7. Rule 3218 and description = Decl File scope....

In Second example standard is missing.

What I need as output is

```
<tr>
    <td>Filename</td>
    <td>Line</td>
    <td>Rank</td>
    <td>Coding Standard</td>
    <td>Rule</td>
    <td>Description</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>project\Src\a.c </td>
    <td>45</td>
    <td>intended</td>
    <td>7.7.</td>
    <td>3218</td>
    <td>Decl File scope...</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>project\Src\x.c </td>
    <td>132</td>
    <td>deviation</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>3218</td>
    <td>Decl File scope...</td>
</tr>
```

What I have tried so far is

```
<tr>
                <td>Filename</td>
                <td>Line</td>
                <td>Rank</td>
                <td>Standard</td>
                <td>Rule</td>
                <td>Description</td>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="issues/warning">
                <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@file"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@line"/></td>
                </tr>
                <xsl:analyze-string select="@message"
                                    regex="\s*([intended|deviation])\s+(.*)\s+(\d+)\s+(.*)">
                    <xsl:matching-substring>
                        <tr>

                            <td><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(3)"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(4)"/></td>
                        </tr>

                    </xsl:matching-substring>

                    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                        <tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
                            </tr>

                        </tr>

                    </xsl:non-matching-substring>

                </xsl:analyze-string>

            </xsl:for-each>
```

But it is not working to my expectation. Rows and values are mixing up.
How to detect if optional standard is present or not?
Any hints to solve the problem is appreciated.

Comment: Note that your XML has `warning` elements, but your XSLT is looking for `error` elements. Is this a typo? Thanks!

Comment: @TimC thank you.. My example was just a sample. I also have error tags as well in xml. I should have edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the expression you may need is `\s*(intended|deviation)\s+(.+\s+)?(\d+)\s+(.*)` (Note the use of `?` for zero-or-one occurrences)

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="issues/warning">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@file"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@line"/></td>
        <xsl:analyze-string select="@message"
                            regex="\s*(intended|deviation)\s+(.+\s+)?(\d+)\s+(.*)">
          <xsl:matching-substring>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(3)"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(4)"/></td>
          </xsl:matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncdD7mb